# Is there any way I can list the inotify events supported by Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, inotify

I need a list of Inotify events supported by the specific version of kernel. Is there any way to find the list of events?

OR I have to assume from already existing list of events supported by Kernel version?
Ex:

```
- IN_ACCESS, IN_MODIFY, IN_CREATE, IN_DELETE... are supported by version 2.6.13
- IN_DONT_FOLLOW starts support from version 2.6.15+
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the source code:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/inotify.h

Regarding kernel version I am not sure. If you do not need automated approach, maybe you can just search through the history of the file: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/include/linux/inotify.h